# Windows server 2003 DNS Issue. I cannot open a specific external website from internal Domain

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory, windows-server-2003, internal-dns

Our public website was hacked and Google blacklisted it. We have fixed and it's visible for the public. This morning I wanted to see the site from our internal domain and I couldn't open it. Chrome says "ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED" and Firefox says "Server not found".

I called our web hosting and they said that the site is up. I used our ISP's DNS on my station and I was able to open the site from our domain. It seems to be that our DNS server is not resolving our public website. All other sites are working properly.

I checked the DNS event and I found these 2 errors:

1.- `The DNS server was unable to create a resource record for  dcdc4d12-7196-4fa4-a70e-8f18e9cfbfe1._msdcs.daynite.local. in zone daynite.local. The Active Directory definition of this resource record is corrupt or contains an invalid DNS name. The event data contains the error.`

2.- `The DNS server was unable to create a resource record for  7dda30db-4d55-442d-bb58-07a3692fa5f1._msdcs.daynite.local. in zone daynite.local. The Active Directory definition of this resource record is corrupt or contains an invalid DNS name. The event data contains the error.`

I am able to ping the site as ourwebsite.com and nslookup also worked.

The same errors above were logged in 2015 and I was able to open the company site before and after. I don't think those errors are preventing from open the site, it must be something else.

Any suggestions?

Thank you,

Comment: When you ping "ourwebsite.com" internally does it resolve to the same IP address that it does when you ping it externally (or if you look up the DNS record at a site like dnsquery.org)?

Comment: In a computer out of my domain the ip of ourwebsite.com is different from a computer in my domain. It looks like my Windows DNS server is not resolving the right ip address.

Answer (score 0):

Go into your DNS server and find the zone for your company website and update the appropriate record to the correct IP from an external DNS server.

Comment: In dnsmgmt, the only place where I found the ourwebsite record was in Cached Lookups->com->ourwebsite and the Host A record has the right ip address as the computer outside my domain. I also tried from the sever tracert www.ourdomain.com and says "Unable to resolve target system name www.ourwebsite.com". In the computer outside our domain tracert works fine.